# Why is my emulator starting in the tablet environment?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using the android-sdk_r12. When I a run my project, I am getting the tablet environment. How can I get the mobile phone environment? Should I install another SDK?

Comment: @citizen: I understand what Robin is asking (as does Vinay) - by default Robin's emulator is creating a 'tablet' environment rather than a 'mobile phone' one. What he/she is asking is 'how to create a mobile phone emulator'.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project and under "Run As" click "Run Configurations". Select your desired target AVD.

Comment: You'll need to choose something with an API level of 10 or below. Anything higher is a tablet.

Comment: "Anything higher is a tablet" - that was correct during Honeycomb but before ICS. Now ICS (4.0) is for both smartphones and tablets.

Answer (score 0):

You would have created a device with Android version >= 3.0.
Create another device for a mobile platform and choose it while running your application.

Answer (score 0):

if your question is `how to create a mobile phone emulator`
Check this

- [Tea Vui Huang's Android Page](http://teavuihuang.com/android/), where you can download different device skins
- [Common Android Virtual Device Configurations](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/), where it clearly describes you the steps to create different Android Emulator to mimic the behavior of different devices